# Content Security Policy in AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am facing a strange error I cannot figure out. When trying to deploy a small project to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance, I am getting a number of CSP errors. It appears to be complaining about executing an inline script, even though my project contains no javascript except for a small Node.js backend to handle some routes. The error I am getting is this:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following 
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 
https://d2aafqm3hbgbf6.cloudfront.net 
https://d2q66yyjeovezo.cloudfront.net 
https://d1idiovbex4hy4.cloudfront.net 
https://d3e2aud6m9sl41.cloudfront.net https://phd.aws.amazon.com 
https://resources.console.aws.amazon.com https://signin.aws.amazon.com 
*.signin.aws.amazon.com https://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net 
https://media.amazonwebservices.com 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' 
keyword, a hash ('sha256-
WkLxG82JrIV0IxhYdEMt3pgYi6ZRYB9ZAj35iFKh8N8='), or a nonce 
('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I tried to add CSP headers to all my requests in both the Node.js backend and the HTML file it serves.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.header("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 
   'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;");
   next();
})
```

Meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
```

Can somebody please help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you.

I got the same error with Laravel on Beanstalk and it was because of an internal error of my php app, not "Content Security Policy".

So, any error that happens in your app to show the page, could produce the error. You can look at your log file in "/var/log/containers/YourContainerName" of your EC2 and solve the issues. For me, it was just wrong permission of "laravel storage folder".

Also, there's a similar issue on amazon that may help if you do load balance.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=783941